# Show that $f(x)$ is not coercive.

Tags: vectors, special-functions

Let $a \in \mathbb R^n$ be a fixed vector. Define $f(x)$ on $\mathbb R^n$ by $f(x)=a\cdot x$

1) Show that $f(x)$ is not coercive.

1) Show that if $\epsilon >0$ , then $g(x)=f(x)+\epsilon ||x||^2$ is coercive.

How can I prove this ? 
So far I'm stuck without a single clue.

Comment: What's the _definition_ of coercive vector field / function? Have you tried applying that and inserting your $f$?

Comment: @Arthur  $f $ is coercive if $\lim_{||x|| \to \infty} f(x) =+ \infty$ . Then $\lim_{||x|| \to \infty} f(x) =\lim_{||x|| \to \infty} a \cdot x =a\lim_{||x|| \to \infty} x$ . Thne what sir ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take the limit of $f$ on the direction that is orthogonal to $a$, say $x=\gamma a^{\perp}$ for $\gamma\to\infty$, then 
$$
\lim_{||x|| \to \infty} f(x) =0.
$$
This means that the limit is not always infinity and varies based on the direction (actually it does not exist!).

Consider the function $g$ and see that:
$$
g(x)=f(x)+\epsilon \|x\|^2=\|\sqrt\epsilon x+\frac{a}{2\sqrt{\epsilon}}\|^2-\frac{\|a\|^2}{4\epsilon}.
$$
See that : 
$$
\|\sqrt\epsilon x+\frac{a}{2\sqrt{\epsilon}}\|^2\geq \epsilon \|x\|^2-\frac{\|a\|^2}{4\epsilon}.
$$
And taking the limit shows what you want.

Comment: Can you please explain me how you got the inequality please

Comment: This is just triangle inequality.